# Error running YOURPROJECTNAME [compile]: JAVA_HOME environment variable not defined IntelliJ 14 along with Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Starting fresh with the new IntelliJ I got this annoying error:

> Error running MYARTIFACTNAME [compile]: JAVA_HOME environment variable not defined

It was a very nostalgic and a bit painful. After a bit of thinking I remembered what was missing:

My JAVA_HOME was set as before but somehow maven couldn't find it from within IntelliJ. So the solution was simple, I had to go to `Preferences > ... > Maven > Runner` and just set the JRE value to my current version of Java home that is 1.8.

Answer (score 4):

My JAVA_HOME was set like before but somehow maven couldn't find it from within IntelliJ. So the solution was simple, I had to go to `Preferences > ... > Maven > Runner` and just set the JRE value to my current version (`1.8`) of Java home folder.

Other things to keep in mind is to make sure your target and source are set to the same version of JAVA in your pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error 7 years later - the solution was the same as in AmirHd's answer.

While we have a project JDK set, we also need to set up a jdk for Maven to use.  These could be the same or different.

The Maven JDK is configured in:

Preferences --> Build, Execution Deployment --> Build Tools --> Maven --> Runner --> JRE (drop-down list)

The error goes away once this JDK too is set.

Comment: Thanks for reconfirming can you please give the question and the answer thump ups. thank you!